# Bootstrap suddenly overriding custom CSS in Create React App only on local build

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

As the title describes, I am finding that bootstrap is suddenly overriding my custom styles when I run my app using `npm run start`. Running from a production build still works as expected, and my files are fine.

I am loading the bootstrap cdn in my index.html, and then loading the custom stylesheets in the index.js or in the component .js files, which as far as I know ensures that the custom styles are loaded after the bootstrap files.

This configuration has worked perfectly for about 3 months, but today I suddenly find that any element with a bootstrap style is being overridden by the styling from bootstrap, and I can see that my custom styles are being deprioritized in my code all the way to the very bottom of the styling hierarchy. This is new and not reflective of any changes to my code -- as it still appears to work perfectly in production builds.

Could this be due to the cdn's loading so slowly that they actually end up loading *after* the custom css?

Answer (score 0):

Every UI framework contains components that should be able to be redesigned or that have capabilities to override existing CSS styles. These skills also apply to react-bootstrap, which provides the ability to modify the current styles to some extent.

It's always handy to override CSS because components may need to be modified based on the project requirements.
[enter link description here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/override-react-bootstrap-with-custom-css-file)